# Small random number generating program?

Tags: c++, c++11, random

My professor gave us the following program as a random number generator

```
//program to demonstrate random number generator

#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib> //needed for random number generation
#include<ctime> //needed for random number generation
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int myRandom = 0;

  srand(time(NULL)); //seed random number generator - only needs to be done once

  //generate a random number from 1 to 10

  myRandom = rand()%10 + 1; //include this code whenever you want a random number generated

  //display the random number
  cout<<"Random number = "<<myRandom<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I would like to know if changing the "10" in the line

```
 myRandom = rand()%10 + 1;
```

to "20" would give me a random number between 1 and 20, and so on.

Comment: Do you know what `%` is?

Comment: You might want to read a basic tutorial about how the modulo operator `%` works,

Comment: If you compile and run it you would find out.

Comment: @Thomas Joachim I understand how the modulo operator works, I just didn't know what kind of number rand() would give me because I didn't know what the line srand(time(NULL)) was

Comment: @NathanOliver If I did that I would need to run it about 40 times in order to see that I never get an output higher than 20. Same with 21, 22, ......

Comment: Or you could put the myRandom in a loop, execute it say 1000 times, then do a min max if to catch values outside your expected range

Comment: Try to find [a good reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) and search for it there.

Comment: While this is partly an RTD, I think it warrants a good answer here. The algorithm used to confuse me a smidge, so it often helps to have it broken down. I've linked to the docs in my answer, though.

Comment: @JasonMc92 what is an RTD?

Comment: RTD stands for "Read The Documentation", and is a common statement of complaint that the answer was in the documentation, so the question was not fully justified. In your case, I believe this question only partially was a case of RTD, as I said...the algorithm can be a little confusing if you're new to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, it does.** This comes down to how the function works.

`rand()` ([docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/RAND_MAX/)) is a **pseudo-random** number generator. That's important - it isn't actually random, and it can get rather predictable if it isn't used right. If you want more unpredictable numbers, that's a far more complex thing. If you want truly random, that's some insane computing!

I digress.

When you call `rand()`, it returns an integer between 0 and some large number known as `RAND_MAX` ([docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/RAND_MAX/)). In order to control the upper range, you have to use the modulus `%` operator ([docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/modulus/)), which returns the remainder of division, instead of the quotient.

That comes down to basic math logic - any number divided by **10** can never have a remainder that is equal to or larger than 10. Similarly, any number divided by **257** can never have a remainder equal to or larger than 257.

Thus, the modulus's second operand sets the **non-inclusive maximum value** - we will always be one less than it.

However, we have a problem - the lowest possible result we can get both from `rand()` and from the modulus `%` itself, is 0. (280/280 = 1, remainder **0**). Thus, we have to offset the result.

This is why we **add a value** to set the lower value. The lowest possible random number in the algorithm is **0 + the number we specify**.

Thus, since `rand % 20` can yield 0 at the lowest, if we add `1` to it, that lowest value is now 1. The side benefit is that, since the inclusive maximum was 19, that moves up to 20. Yay!

```
rand() % 20 + 1 //Yields number between 1-20
```

However, we once again have another caveat. If we add anything larger than one, we are shifting that maximum number upwards! In the case of `rand % 20 + 3`, the lowest value is 3, but the highest is now *22*, which we do NOT want! How do we offset that?

This requires a little bit of math cleverness on our part, now. The right operand on the modulus must be changed so it, plus the offset, equal the **non-inclusive maximum**.

```
rand() % 18 + 3 //Yields number between 3 and 20 inclusively.
```

---

In short, the right operand of the addition is the **inclusive minimum**, and the sum of the two numbers is the **non-inclusive maximum**.